# How use React animations to animate every item differently?

Tags: javascript, animation, reactjs, react-router, react-animated

I have a bunch of items that will be shown 1 at a time and on mount/unmount will animate between itself and the next item. But I want them all to animate in different ways.

Is this possible using `ReactCSSTransitionGroup`? It seems from the code, that it is not and only allows one animation definition per group:

```
    <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
      transitionName="example"
      transitionEnterTimeout={500}
      transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>
      {items}
    </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
```

What about `ReactTransitionGroup`? It seems this could work. Is it my only option?

> ReactTransitionGroup is the basis for animations. When children are
>   declaratively added or removed from it special lifecycle hooks are 
>   called on them.

Am I reading that correctly, that each child will be told "you're leaving" or "you're entering", and then it will do the animations itself (either CSS animations or jQuery, etc)?

Is there a better way to do this (differing animations within a group)?

Comment: if only the mounting animation is different, you can just use CSS to do it.

Comment: @xiaofan2406 How? It specifies one class per group, not per item.

Comment: If you only want item to appear with different animations, you don't need `ReactCSSTransitionGroup`. Use normal CSS classes, each item has its own classes corresponds to the animation you like.

Comment: @xiaofan2406 And how do i give them those classes only in enter/leave?

Comment: Same question here, how do i give them those classes only in enter/leave?